# Referencing Auto Generated Abs referenced files from within a Project?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have the given structure:

```
proj
|-- app.py
|-- classes
| |-- __init__.py
| \-- myclass.py
\-- services
  |-- generatedpython
  |  |- a.py
  |  \- a_grpc.py
  |-- a.py
  |-- a_grpc.py
  |-- protobuf.py
  \-- transactions.py
```

and throughout my application, I use relative imports. Hence from the root directory, I would just run: `python3 app.py` but even since adding auto-built code to the project, I'm having issues and I didn't want to augment auto-generated code.

How can I fix this? I was thinking that I could do some imports from within `__init__.py`?

```
#-- transactions
from ..services.protobuf import A,B,C

#-- protobuf
try:
  from ..services.a_grpc import Stub
except Exception as e:          # Exception thrown, No Module named 'generatedpython'
  print("Exception: ", e)       #     from generatedpython import generatedpython_pb2
  from a_grpc import Stub       #     This exists from within the Generated Code
```

Since it cant seem to find this, which exists if i run it as a standalone file, my thought is to leverage the `__init__.py` to find and import it  Not sure what can be done though since my biggest issue is that i cant touch generated code, but i could use `__init__` as some sort of wrapper.

what should I do to manage this?

I was thinking to do something like:

```
#-- __init__.py
from ..services.generatedpython import *
# ...
```

but that doenst work since the underlying files seem relate to each other.  At this time, im trying to import items in a particular order and see if that works.

I was doing some tests, and was trying to update the **init** people with some data.

```
# -- __init__.py
from ../services import generatedpython as generatedpyyhon
# I was thinking that would create it as a generatedpython module such that it could be consumed on follow on elements. Doesnt seem to be the case though.
# I was also trying to manage all the modules in __init__ with load order etc, but it seems that when referencing generatedpython in the pre generated code, it would still error.
```

*EDIT*:  Still having issues, but i was thinking that since modules looks in the path folders for the respective modules, I was trying to add it to the path.  I was doing:

`sys.path.insert(0, os.abspath(os.dirname(".")))`

I was thinking that adding that folder to the path, would enable all python files therein to be referenced correctly with an import.

Comment: Where is the `app.py` file in your project?

Comment: let me edit thank you.  It is a sibling of services and classes.

Comment: @reddynishanth I did an update.  I was hoping that I could abstract the module to an alias so that way the pregenerated code woudl see the required modules and use them, but seems to not work.

Comment: Were your `a.py` and `a_grpc.py` originally called `a_pb2.py` and `a_pb2_grpc.py`? In general, you should not change these names since [they are referenced by other generated files](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/75041ea3a933c46de558130f6d6864f0619eaaa9/examples/python/helloworld/helloworld_pb2_grpc.py#L4). Can you please include your proto files as well as your protoc invocation? As it is, it's difficult to figure out the structure of your generated code and the exact error you're running into.

Comment: I created a MVP that would show the use case, but youre correct.  I will see if i can post it.  I am thinking that I might just end up using a setup file to just deploy it as a library and then boom reference it that way